# How do I calculate - divide outerWidth of HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a header with a 100% width. In this header I have a title and an image. The image always fills up 4/12ths of the header and the title must be centered in 8/12ths of the header.

I have made some variables with jQuery that specify the outerWidth of the title and the header (see code below). I think I should calculate it as follows to position my header title: divide my header by 12 and multiply it by 8 - half the width of my header title.

```
$header_title_width = $('.header h2').outerWidth();
$header_title_height = $('.header h2').outerHeight();
$header_devided_width = $('header').outerWidth() / 12 * 8;

alert($header_devided_width);
```

The alert returns a zero, so I think it is not possible to use `*` or `/` the way I use it. Next I tried to calculate inside a `css()` function but this doesn't work as well, see the code below

```
$('.header h2').css("left", "calc((" + $header_width / 12 * 8 + "px - " + $header_title_width + "px) - " + $header_title_width / 2 + "px)");
```

When I devide a variable by 2 it seems to work, see the code below

```
$('.header h2').css("top", "calc(50% - " + $header_title_height / 2 + "px)");
```

I'm hoping my explanation is clear. Is there someone who can explain how I calculate with jQuery?

The HTML / LESS

```
<div class="header col-md-12">
<h2 class="col-md-8">The war on drugs <br /> a deeper understanding</h2>
<a href="#">Pre order now</a>
```

```
.header {
height: 265px;
background-image: @header-bg;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;

h2 {
    color: @white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 27px;
    top: ~"calc(50% - (54px / 2))";
}

a {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: @green;
    text-align: center;
    color: @white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    left: ~"calc((530px / 2) - (120px / 2))";
    top: ~"calc(50% + 54px)";
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please add your HTML and CSS to the question. I'm certain there's a better way of doing what you need without using JS as a crutch.

Comment: `html` , `css` ? remove these tags. anyone.

Comment: It looks like it's not jQuery you have trouble with, but simple math: `x / 12 * 8 = x/96` not `x * 0.(6)`! You probably want `(x/12) * 8`, `x * 8/12` or `x * 2/3`.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I used brackets to condition the calculation but it always returns zero, thats why I asked this platform for help.

Comment: Well, I used what you posted and that's never going to give you two thirds of header width. Are you suggesting I should have ignored it, considering your question?

Comment: I changed my approach, this question can be marked as resolved.

Comment: If you found an answer, post it as an answer!

Comment: I cant post answers. It seems I have posted low quality questions/answers in the past when my coding knowledge wasn't 'good enough'